# Media query for screen not work

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to change font size according to screen size in my materialize.css. But it isn't working. What am I doing wrong exactly?

```
 @media screen and (min-device-width: 600) and  (max-device-width: 1500) {
h1{
    font-size: 2em;
}
h5{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
}}
```

Comment: Hi, You must write the value along with its units. 600px and 1500px - Help :)

Comment: Length values in CSS always need a unit, unless the value is 0.

Comment: try `@media  (min-width: 600px) and  (max-width: 1500px){...}` ?

Comment: exactly . I saw it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add px to value

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 600px) and  (max-device-width: 1500px) {
h1{
    font-size: 2em;
}
h5{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do add `px` to the widths such as `600px` not 600.
Also, do put this meta tag at the top `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

A `meta` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.
The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.